# MahApps DateTimePicker custom datetime format

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am using the **DateTimePicker** control of **MahApps**.

```
<controls:DateTimePicker 
    SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDateTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
    SelectedTimeFormat="Short" 
    SelectedDateFormat="Short"
    Culture="en-In"/>
```

Currently it's showing datetime in `dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm` format.But I need to show that in `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm Z` format. I see currently it has no property which takes datetime format as string pattern. **So how to do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the control doesn't support this. You can override the `GetValueForTextBox` method to achieve this

```
public class MyDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    protected override string GetValueForTextBox()
    {
        return SelectedDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z");
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<local:MyDateTimePicker />
```